# Can not find selector when exchange method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I come across a problem when trying to exchange method:

```
@implementation LoginViewModel

+ (void)load {

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Method fromMethod = class_getClassMethod([NSURL class], @selector(URLWithString:));
        Method toMethod = class_getClassMethod([self class], @selector(TempURLWithString:));
        method_exchangeImplementations(fromMethod, toMethod);
    }
});

}

+ (NSURL *)TempURLWithString:(NSString *)URLString {
    NSLog(@"url: %@", URLString);
    return [LoginViewModel TempURLWithString:URLString];
}
```

When calling [NSURL URLWithString:], I successfully get the parameter in the exchanged method TempURLWithString:. But it crashed when returning the result from the original implementation:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[LoginViewModel 
URLWithString:relativeToURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 
0x10625ff80'
```

What I want to do is modifying the url String when init NSURL, any one can give me some help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of `+[NSURL URLWithString:]` is basically the following:

```
+ (NSURL *)URLWithString:(NSString *)string {
    return [self URLWithString:string relativeToURL:nil];
}
```

The important thing to note here is that the `self` refers to the `NSURL` class.

However, when you call `[LoginViewModel TempURLWithString:URLString]`, the `self` in the original `URLWithString:` method is now a reference to the `LoginViewModel` class, meaning that when the original implementation calls `[self URLWithString:string relativeToURL:nil]`, that call gets dispatched to `+[LoginViewModel URLWithString:relativeToURL:]`, which doesn't exist (hence the exception).

You can fix this by also adding a stub for `URLWithString:relativeToURL` to your class which just forwards the call to `+[NSURL URLWithString:relativeToURL:]`:

```
@implementation LoginViewModel
+ (NSURL *)URLWithString:(NSString *)string relativeToURL:(nullable NSURL *)relativeURL {
    return [NSURL URLWithString:string relativeToURL:relativeURL];
}
@end
```